# ORACLE - When splitting a partition, can I meanwhile still read data in it?

Tags: oracle, partitioning, partition, database-partitioning

### Statements

- let say I have a schema partitioned by range of date (but no subpartitions)
- let say I have partition P1 in this schema containing a lot of rows
- at some point, let say I want to split it
- as the partition is full of rows, split time takes up from 1 to 3 seconds

### During the split period, can I:

- **still read data contained in the reference partition (e.g. P1)?**
- **still read data moving OR already moved into the new partition created?**

### According to documentation:

I didn't find anything stated in the official documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/statements_3001.htm#sthref3944
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/part_admin002.htm#i1008028
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-65E169AC-3224-405E-AD1D-9FBF4D5231BA.htm
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-6BB84952-7021-4CBA-91ED-180E0656E02B.htm#VLDBG00303

However, they sometimes mention a lock. But does this "lock" avoid writing only or also for reading/writing ?

### Before you ask to test it by myself:

The usual split time is still less than a second but we get, sometimes, an issue to split our reference partition. Also, our splitting time is unpredictable. Finally, we do not always read data in this partition, so we would need to insert fresh data and thus fill as much a partition and then try to split and read, which is quite complex.

So if anyone knows the answer, would be much more better

Comment: You can create a "large" table with lots of `varchar2(4000)` columns and schedule jobs of `split` and `insert/select` to reproduce the workload with no need to perform "fast" manual operations. You may also scale this test case with more jobs. Oracle never provide raw data, so you'll never read the same data twice.

Comment: This process is [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/vldbg/maintenance-partition-tables-indexes.html#GUID-6BB84952-7021-4CBA-91ED-180E0656E02B): *Partition maintenance with SPLIT operations are supported as online operations with the keyword ONLINE for heap organized tables, enabling concurrent DML operations while a partition maintenance operation is ongoing.*

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with range and dates why worry about splitting PARTITIONS? You can use intervals and every time a new date (day, week, month, quarter, year) is added the PARTITION will be automatically added therefore alleviating the need to split partitions.

Below is a setup for a daily PARTITION and some tools to renane the PARTITION and drop older PARTITION if you wanted them dropped after a certain period.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ddl(p_cmd varchar2) 
 authid current_user
is
t1 pls_integer;
BEGIN 
t1 := dbms_utility.get_time; 

dbms_output.put_line(p_cmd);

 execute immediate p_cmd;

dbms_output.put_line((dbms_utility.get_time - t1)/100 || ' seconds');

END;
/

CREATE TABLE PARTITION_RETENTION (
   seq_num NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
    TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(30),
    RETENTION INTERVAL DAY(3) TO SECOND(0),
 CONSTRAINT
partition_retention_pk primary key (table_name),
CONSTRAINT CHK_NON_ZERO_DAYS CHECK (
        RETENTION > INTERVAL '0' DAY
    ),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_WHOLE_DAYS CHECK (
        EXTRACT(HOUR FROM RETENTION) = 0
        AND EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM RETENTION) = 0
        AND EXTRACT(SECOND FROM RETENTION) = 0
    )
);

insert into PARTITION_RETENTION (TABLE_NAME, RETENTION) 
select 'T1', interval '10' day from dual union all
select 'T3', interval '15' day from dual union all
select 'T4', 15 * interval '1' day from dual union all
select 'T5', 5 * interval '1 00:00:00' day to second from dual;

CREATE TABLE t1 (     
 seq_num NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
   dt   DATE
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (dt)
INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(7,'DAY'))
(
   PARTITION OLD_DATA values LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2022-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
);
/

INSERT into t1 (dt)
with dt (dt, interv) as (
select date '2022-01-01', numtodsinterval(1,'DAY') from dual
union all
select dt.dt + interv, interv from dt
where dt.dt + interv < date '2022-02-01')
select dt from dt;
/

create index t1_global_ix on t1 (dt);
/


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MaintainPartitions IS  EXPRESSION_IS_OF_WRONG_TYPE EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(EXPRESSION_IS_OF_WRONG_TYPE, -6550);

    CURSOR PartTables IS
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, INTERVAL
    FROM USER_PART_TABLES 
    WHERE PARTITIONING_TYPE = 'RANGE' 
    ORDER BY TABLE_NAME;

    CURSOR TabParts(aTableName VARCHAR2) IS 
    SELECT PARTITION_NAME, HIGH_VALUE
    FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS
 WHERE regexp_like(partition_name,'^SYS_P[[:digit:]]{1,10}')  AND
 TABLE_NAME = aTableName AND
table_name not like 'BIN$%'
      and    interval is not null
    ORDER BY PARTITION_POSITION;

    ym INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH;
    ds INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND;
    newPartName VARCHAR2(30);
    PERIOD TIMESTAMP;

BEGIN

    FOR aTab IN PartTables LOOP 
        BEGIN       
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := '||aTab.INTERVAL||'; END;' USING OUT ds;
            ym := NULL; 
        EXCEPTION 
            WHEN EXPRESSION_IS_OF_WRONG_TYPE THEN
                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := '||aTab.INTERVAL||'; END;' USING OUT ym;
                ds := NULL;         
        END;            

        FOR aPart IN TabParts(aTab.TABLE_NAME) LOOP         
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := '||aPart.HIGH_VALUE||'; END;' USING OUT PERIOD;
            IF ds IS NOT NULL THEN
                IF ds >= INTERVAL '7' DAY THEN
                    -- Weekly partition
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := TO_CHAR('||aPart.HIGH_VALUE||' - :int, :fmt); END;' USING OUT newPartName, INTERVAL '1' DAY, '"P_"IYYY"W"IW';
                ELSE
                    -- Daily partition
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := TO_CHAR('||aPart.HIGH_VALUE||' - :int, :fmt); END;' USING OUT newPartName, INTERVAL '1' DAY, '"P_"YYYYMMDD';
                END IF;
            ELSE
                IF ym = INTERVAL '3' MONTH THEN
                    -- Quarterly partition 
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := TO_CHAR('||aPart.HIGH_VALUE||' - :int, :fmt); END;' USING OUT newPartName, INTERVAL '1' DAY, '"P_"YYYY"Q"Q';
                ELSE
                    -- Monthly partition
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := TO_CHAR('||aPart.HIGH_VALUE||' - :int, :fmt); END;' USING OUT newPartName, INTERVAL '1' DAY, '"P_"YYYYMM';
                END IF;
            END IF;

            IF newPartName <> aPart.PARTITION_NAME THEN
                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||aTab.TABLE_NAME||' RENAME PARTITION '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME||' TO '||newPartName;
            END IF;             
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;

END MaintainPartitions;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE rebuild_index
authid current_user
is

BEGIN 
        for i in (
            select index_owner, index_name, partition_name, 'partition' ddl_type
           from all_ind_partitions
           where status = 'UNUSABLE'
           union all
           select owner, index_name, null, null
           from all_indexes
           where status = 'UNUSABLE'
       )
       loop
         if i.ddl_type is null then
          ddl('alter index '||i.index_owner||'.'||i.index_name||' rebuild parallel 4 online');
         else
          ddl('alter index '||i.index_owner||'.'||i.index_name||' modify '||i.ddl_type||' '||i.partition_name||' rebuild parallel 4 online');
         end if;
       end loop;
 END;
/


EXEC MaintainPartitions;


DECLARE
    CANNOT_DROP_LAST_PARTITION EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(CANNOT_DROP_LAST_PARTITION, -14758);

    CANNOT_DROP_ONLY_ONE_PARTITION EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(CANNOT_DROP_ONLY_ONE_PARTITION, -14083);

   ts TIMESTAMP;
 
   CURSOR TablePartitions IS
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, PARTITION_NAME, p.HIGH_VALUE, t.INTERVAL, RETENTION, DATA_TYPE
    FROM USER_PART_TABLES t
        JOIN USER_TAB_PARTITIONS p USING (TABLE_NAME)
        JOIN USER_PART_KEY_COLUMNS pk ON pk.NAME = TABLE_NAME
        JOIN USER_TAB_COLS tc USING (TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME)
        JOIN PARTITION_RETENTION r USING (TABLE_NAME)
    WHERE        pk.object_type     = 'TABLE' AND
   t.partitioning_type = 'RANGE' AND 
    REGEXP_LIKE (tc.data_type, '^DATE$|^TIMESTAMP.*'); 

BEGIN

    FOR aPart IN TablePartitions LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := '||aPart.HIGH_VALUE||'; END;' USING OUT ts;
        IF ts < SYSTIMESTAMP - aPart.RETENTION THEN
            BEGIN
             ddl('alter table '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' drop partition '||aPart.partition_name);
 
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN CANNOT_DROP_ONLY_ONE_PARTITION THEN
                    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cant drop the only partition '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME ||' from table '||aPart.TABLE_NAME);
  
   ddl('ALTER TABLE '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' TRUNCATE PARTITION '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME);
                                                   WHEN CANNOT_DROP_LAST_PARTITION THEN
                    BEGIN
                        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Drop last partition '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME ||' from table '||aPart.TABLE_NAME);
                        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' SET INTERVAL ()';
 
 ddl('alter table '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' drop partition '||aPart.partition_name);

                        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' SET INTERVAL( '||aPart.INTERVAL||' )';            
                    EXCEPTION
                        WHEN CANNOT_DROP_ONLY_ONE_PARTITION THEN 
                            -- Depending on the order the "last" partition can be also the "only" partition at the same time
                                                 
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' SET INTERVAL( '||aPart.INTERVAL||' )';    

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cant drop the only partition '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME ||' from table '||aPart.TABLE_NAME);
  
         ddl('ALTER TABLE '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' TRUNCATE PARTITION '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME);                
               END;
            END;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
   rebuild_index();
END;
```